# Schedule computation concurrently for all elements of the fs2.Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

I have an `fs2.Stream` consisting of some elements (probably infinite) and I want to schedule some computation for all elements of the stream concurrently to each other. Here is what I tried

```
implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)
implicit val timer: Timer[IO]     = IO.timer(ExecutionContext.global)

val stream = for {
  id <- fs2.Stream.emits(List(1, 2)).covary[IO]
  _ <- fs2.Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second)
  _ <- fs2.Stream.eval(IO(println(id)))
} yield ()

stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

The program output looks like

```
1
1
1
etc...
```

which is not what's expected. I'd like to interleave the scheduled computation for all of the elements of the original stream, but not wait until the first stream terminates (which never happens due to the infinite scheduling).

Comment: Do you mean you want that elements of the 1st stream appear in the order with 1 second interval?
Or do you want to 1 and 2 appear at once and then repeat with 1 second interval?

Comment: `flatMap` is sequential but you want parallel processing. You can get that using `zip`.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik I want the computation is run every 1 second for all elements of the original stream in parallel

Comment: It would be easier if you'd provide your expected result because it's hard to understand what do you want to achieve. Can you switch `id <- fs2.Stream.emits(List(1, 2)).covary[IO]` with `_ <- fs2.Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second)` and check if it will as you intended?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Yes, exactly. But can it be done without switching because scheduling interval may depend on the element value itself?

Comment: You could for example do `fs2.Stream.emits(List(1, 2)).covary[IO].delayBy(1.second).repeat`. But as I said it's hard to tell what is your intent. I think you'd benefit by editing your question and providing better expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val str = for {
  id <- Stream.emits(List(1, 5, 7)).covary[IO]
  res = timer.sleep(id.second) >> IO(println(id))
} yield res

val stream =  str.parEvalMapUnordered(5)(identity)

stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

or

```
 val stream = Stream.emits(List(1, 5, 7))
   .map { id => 
     Stream.eval(timer.sleep(id.second) >> IO(println(id))) }
   .parJoinUnbounded

stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to hints given by @KrzysztofAtłasik and @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez here is the solution I just came up with:

```
val originalStream = fs2.Stream.emits(List(1, 2))

val scheduledComputation = originalStream.covary[IO].map({ id =>
        fs2.Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second).evalMap(_ => IO.delay(println(id)))
}).fold(fs2.Stream.empty.covaryAll[IO, Unit])((result, stream) => result.merge(stream)).flatten
```

The solution that @KrzysztofAtłasik proposed in the comment with interleaving
`id <- fs2.Stream.emits(List(1, 2)).covary[IO]` and `_ <- fs2.Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second)` also works, but it does not allow to schedule each element in its own way.

To schedule elements concurrently for `elementValue` seconds it is possible to do the following:

```
val scheduleEachElementIndividually = originalStream.covary[IO].map({ id =>
                                 //id.seconds
        fs2.Stream.awakeEvery[IO](id.second).evalMap(_ => IO.delay(println(id)))
}).fold(fs2.Stream.empty.covaryAll[IO, Unit])((result, stream) => result.merge(stream)).flatten
```